# How can I remove a burn mark on finished wood without replacing the piece entirely?

Tags: bathroom, wood, damage

Our new home has a wooden bathroom vanity with an obvious blackened burn mark on it below the mirror, perhaps from a candle burning too close for too long. What are some ways I can remove the mark? I though about sanding it down but it may look bad, any other options?

The vanity is wood lined with a tri-mirror set up in the center, the burn mark is along the bottom edge.

Comment: hide it behind something (picture, shaving mirror,...)

Comment: Kind of an option but I'd rather not just hang something on my bathroom mirror, probably more distracting than the black mark.

Comment: What's the wood finished with? This will be a bit factor in how to repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to a hardware store and get some good wood putty, filler or epoxy that can be molded and sanded.  Now sand out the burnt part of the molding.  Apply the putty in where you have sanded and have it roughly conform to the shape of your wood work.  Then let it dry to the time as shown on the manufacturer directions.  Now sand to match the rest of the molding.  Stain or paint to match.  Probably the hardest part is to match the stain, if it is stained.

Comment: I've never had great results with staining filler. for that reason, I might pause to consider the "less is more" approach. After sanding the burn mark out, can you live with the resulting dimple in the wood? If so, you might consider leaving out the filler and going straight to stain.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the iron trick when we had our kitchen table burned with a hot pan, but I'm not sure if that would work with a black burn mark, it depends on how the wood was burned. Our table, for example, was basically burned with steam, and the burn mark was white. We placed a lightly damp cloth over the burn mark, and then ironed on top of the cloth. The steam created by the iron actually pulled the burn mark out of the table fairly well.

If you think your burn mark was created in a similar way, you can look up videos on youtube of other people using this same method.

Good luck!